# adjusting formatting of footnotes in tex4ht's .docx output

Tags: tex4ht, msword, latex-to-word

A default Word document formats footnotes as follows: at the bottom of the page, the footnote hook (e.g., the number '1') appears in superscript, then there is a `space`, then the footnote text begins. The ruling on the left and right is the same as the main text above.

When I run `tex4ht` (and then convert the `.odt` output to `.docx` format), the result formats footnotes quite differently: it begins with the footnote hook *not in superscript*, then includes a *tab* instead of a space, then begins footnote text. The footnote text is ruled with a *hanging indent*.

Is there a way to adjust `tex4ht`'s output so that the footnotes are formatted according as in Word's default?

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text goes here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


Text.\footnote{This is a long footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote. This is a footnote.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text ends here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

LaTeX output:

[image]

Default MS Word output:

[image]

`tex4ht` output:

[image]

## Update based on @Michal.21's answer

When I tested @Michal.21's answer, I got odd output after converting to Word:

[image: Word output]

From looking at the invisible characters, it looks like what's going on is not an extra line but rather something is off about the superscript "1":

[image]

Is there a way to tweak the `.cfg` file so that it is compatible with Word?

## further update with more info from MS Word

The trouble seems to be that rather than use the "Superscript" feature, the "Footnote Characters" (as the Style of the footnote label down below is called in MS Word) font is "8.5 pt, Raised by 12 pt":

[image: Footnote Characters]

By contrast, the "Footnote Anchor" style (for the references in the main body text pointing down to the footnotes) is "Superscript":

[image]

So perhaps one could simply enter the same font information for "Footnote Characters" as is currently used for "Footnote Anchor"?

Comment: As this example shows, `tex4ht` also makes the footnote text 12-point instead of 10-point (as in both the LaTeX output and the MS Word default). It would be nice to be able to tweak that automatically as well.

Comment: It occurs to me that the failure to make the footnote hook superscript could be not intentional but rather a result of the bug I identified [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474005/superscript-not-working-in-footnotes-in-tex4ht-output) whereby the `\textsuperscript` command does not work within footnotes in `tex4ht` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've took a look at the footnote styling code in a file generated by LibreOffice and extracted the following code:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureOO{Footnote}{
<style:style
    style:name="Footnote"
    style:family="paragraph"
    style:parent-style-name="Standard"
    style:class="extra">\Hnewline
  <style:paragraph-properties
             fo:margin-left="0.2in"
             fo:margin-right="0in"
             fo:text-indent="-0.2in"
              style:auto-text-indent="false"/>
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="80\%"
      style:font-size-asian="80\%"
      style:font-size-complex="80\%" />
</style:style>\Hnewline
<text:notes-configuration text:note-class="footnote"
    text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
    text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
    style:num-format="1" text:start-value="0"
    text:footnotes-position="page"
    text:start-numbering-at="document" />\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 70\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_anchor"
style:display-name="Footnote anchor" style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>\Hnewline
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It seems to do the trick:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the ignorant question, but where should I put this code to make it work? I tried putting it in the preamble to the TeX document to be converted to ODT/Word, but it did not have the desired result.

Comment: @AlexRoberts no, you should put it to a `.cfg` file, which then needs to be included using the `-c` option of `make4ht`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I've just tested it out, and somehow the output is a bit odd after the conversion to Word. I'm not sure what's going on, but maybe it's that the superscript isn't converting properly? I'll edit my question to put a screenshot of the output.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with `<style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />` but don't know what the number should be changed to.

Comment: @AlexRoberts I cannot test it in Word, so it is hard to say. Maybe opening and saving the file in LibreOffice could help? (it helps in some cases, I am not sure about this one)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @michal.h21. I tried it but found no change in the Word output. I've updated my question with further information from MS Word. Perhaps that is enough to identify the problem?

Comment: Ah! Now I see what it was, I was fiddling with the wrong one. The solution is to change the percentage in `<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 70\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>` from `70\%` to `58\%`. Thanks again for the fix!