# Superscript not working in footnotes in tex4ht output

Tags: tex4ht, superscripts, latex-to-word

When I use `\textsuperscript` in footnotes (in `memoir` class, compiled with `xetex`), `tex4ht` fails to make the text in question superscript, even though it does so successfully in the main body text.

I suspect this might be related to the same configurations which Michal Hoftich (@michal.h21) used to fix the behavior of superscript in the main body text [a year ago](https://tex4ht.tug.narkive.com/ovPNlTAj/superscript-with-tex4ht).

Is there a way to make the superscript work in the footnotes too?

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text goes here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


Superscript works in the text: 23\textsuperscript{r}.

But not in the footnote.\footnote{23\textsuperscript{r}.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text ends here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: TeX.SE isn't a good place for posting bug reports. Have you tried contacting the maintainer of `tex4ht` directly with the concerns expressed in your five postings?

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I will post a link to this question on the `tex4ht` mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that configuration for footnotes disables superscript with `\let\@textsuperscript\hbox`. It needs to be disabled in the footnote mark, spurious elements would be generated otherwise. After the footnote mark had been printed, it is no longer necessary. I've modified `tex4ht` sources in order to keep this only in the footnote mark. Because TL 2018 is frozen, the change will be available only in the TL 2019 pre-test. The changed `ooffice.4ht` file can be downloaded [here](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/46586a5fc24631feb528839863948aa5).

This is the result:

[image]